Trying to install a 3 way light switch
I’ve tried to replace my 3 way light switch but I have failed to have both light in my bathroom and bedroom simultaneously. After replacing my light switch, the most light I was able to get out of it was light in the bathroom when it was turned on and half the light in my bedroom when it was turned off. There are only 3 black wires in the box coming from 3 different sheaths and 1 ground but no matter how I configure it, it seems to not work. Unsure if I should take out the outlet right next to it and take some of those wires out also but unsure. There isn’t a clear wire that indicates that it’s hot so don’t know which wire goes where.
This is what it currently looks like:


Did it work before you replaced the switch?  Why did you replace the switch?  Is this one of two switches that control the bedroom and bathroom lights together - i.e. all the lights are either on or off, and changing the position of either switch will change the state of all the lights?

Neither bath rooms nor bedrooms usually have a need for a 3way switch.  3way switches are for room that have 2 or more entry points and need to have a light source that can be turned on from either entry.  It can be possible here that the use of a 3way is the cause of the problem.  It's even possible that a previous owner installed the old 3way needlessly and this confused you.

On a 3 way switch you can freely experiment which wire goes where till it works

Apart from "you really should invest not much money in a multimeter"  if the outlet beside it is not switched, the black wire that is connected to that (looks like taped up wirenuts, which is typically a sign of shoddy workmanship) is going to be the hot/live feed. On a normal 3-way (two switches controlling one or more lights) that goes to the common (usually black) screw, and the travelers go to the brass screws. It's not at all clear that's what you have here, since it would be very odd to switch the bathroom and bedroom together. If that's how it was, please [edit] to clarify.

And if it used to work, you definitely want to leave the outlet alone, not borrow wires from it. But again, we don't know why you are attempting to change it since you have not told us that. Please tell us so we can help you. And next time, take pictures of the existing wiring before unhooking anything.

@DIY75 It is a free country (mostly) so you can "freely experiment which wire goes where till it works". But that really isn't the best way to do things. The best way is to figure out, step-by-step, where each cable goes and what is the function of each wire.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact could you explain in details  the The best way is to figure out, step-by-step, where each cable goes and what is the function of each wire.

@DIY75 I have actually written up quite a few posts in that way. The kind of thing where some people respond with "that's way too long" and a -1.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact sorry to hear that, some people do not appreciate your posts
